# Google Cloud function - Document Ai error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cloud-document-ai

I'm trying to write a Firebase cloud function that triggers when an image is uploaded to a specific bucket. It sends that image over to document ai to be processed by a custom processor and logs the return in Firestore database.

I did the same thing with cloud vision and it worked fine. I just needed better parsing than Vision had to offer.

However, when I trigger this new cloud function I keep receiving an error in the Google logs. It started with Error:

> 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.

I added some logging to the code to try and narrow down the problem. eventually, I got this but it was a truncated response.

> statusDetails: [ BadRequest { fieldViolations: [Array] } ]

Just to note I've checked and triple-checked my processor id, project id, and location. I've also checked my service account permissions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { DocumentProcessorServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/documentai').v1beta3;

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./sample-room-58c38-bd767e088e9d.json')),
});

const client = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient({
    projectId: 'sample-room-58c38',
    keyFilename: './sample-room-58c38-bd767e088e9d.json',
});

const bucketName = 'sample-room-58c38-q6gtc';

exports.processImage = functions.storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async (object) => {
        const gcsUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${object.name}`;
        const request = {
            name: `projects/sample-room-58c38/locations/us/processor/a89f2d4fd6b09a9a`,
            inputConfig: {
                gcsDocumentUri: gcsUri,
                mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            },
        };

        console.log('gcsUri:', gcsUri);
        console.log('Request:', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2));

        try {
            const [result] = await client.processDocument(request);

            const { document } = result;
            const { formFields } = document;
            const data = {};

            formFields.forEach(field => {
                const fieldName = field.fieldName.text;
                const fieldValue = field.fieldValue.text;

                
                data[fieldName] = fieldValue;
            });

            console.log('Data:', data);

            return admin.firestore().collection('DocumentAI Photos').doc(object.name).set(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error in processDocument:', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)); // <--- Error logging here
            throw error;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request object structure is not correct.

Currently, The Node.JS Client libraries for Document AI don't allow online (synchronous) processing with documents in Google Cloud Storage, you will need to use Batch processing to process documents in Cloud Storage.

You can refer to the code samples on this page to see how to use the Node.JS client library for [online processing with an uploaded file](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_process_document-nodejs) and [batch processing for files in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_batch_process_document-nodejs)